# How do I get instagram_basic permission during development?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, scope, access-token, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use this endpoint from the Instagram graph api:

```
GET /ig_hashtag_search?user_id={user-id}&q={q}
```

Documentation for this endpoint can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag-search).

I'm running this GET request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/ig_hashtag_search?q=coke&transport=cors&user_id=<my_user_id>&access_token=<my_access_token>&q=coke
```

and get this as response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Requires instagram_basic permission to manage the object",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
    }
}.
```

The user id comes from my instagram account and the access_token that I'm using is a User token generated with "[Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)" and I can see that this token has the scope "instagram_basic" when using the "[Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken)".

I can't understand why this does not work? Do I really need to submit a API review just to test the hashtag endpoint during development?

Please help!

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. I don't have an official website or iOS app, I am simply in the development phase and need access to the API.

Answer (score 0):

I guess sometimes App review team of Facebook doesn't know what is the usage of the permission so they just decline the submissions randomly. I got that permission like 3 months ago and i checked my app review. I send them this text

> We are going to use instagram_basic to read an Instagram account profile's info and media. We will get the basic metadata of an Instagram Business account profile like "USERNAME", "ID", "FOLLOWERS", "FOLLOWING". You can check the Screescast to see how we use the instagram_basic on our app.

**Here is what they saw while they do the app review**
[image: appreview]

Also be careful while you send requests, keep in mind to change it to development mode. Some of the endpoints works only in live mode. The API still changes a lot and there are tons of bugs i see in my project. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Instagram profile(<my_user_id>). It should have public access and should be registered as business account(I'm not 100% sure about last one).